# Given a list L of N elements uniformly sampled from a set A, what is the probability that L contains every element of A?

Tags: probability

For example, if A = {a, b} and N = 3,  your list options are:

- aaa
- **aab**
- **aba**
- **abb**
- **baa**
- **bab**
- **bba**
- bbb

so the probability is 6/8 = 3/4. I feel like this is easier than I'm making it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of surjective functions from $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ to a set $A$ with $m$ members is $S(n,m) m!$, where $S(n,m)$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).  The probability that $L$ contains every element of $A$ is then 
$$ \dfrac{m!}{m^n} S(n,m)$$

Comment: Is there a handy way to approximate this if I have, say, m and n in the trillions, but of similar magnitude?